# Getting the time difference in minutes, hours and days

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to show data like this

1. 10 min ago
2. 1 day ago.
3. 2 month ago

I am receiving data from in `"2014-05-29T08:16:56Z"` format please give me code on how to do this.

Comment: [This](http://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/date_time/datetime11.php) might help to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and also take a look at: [THIS](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-count-down-timer-examples.html)

```
String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
   sdf1.setTimeZone(obj); 

   Date date = sdf1.parse(" your match time ");
   millis = date.getTime();


  long currentTimeInMili = new Date().getTime(); // Current time
  final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(millis - currentTimeInMili, 1 * 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          matchUpcomingText.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished) + "till match start");
}

 public void onFinish() {
matchUpcomingText.setText("Finished!");
   }
 }.start();
```